# Displaying Related Documents OF A Custom Object in VisualForce Page Salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, contentdocument

Good day everyone, I am in a little bit of a pickle and could really your use help.

So I am trying to make a visual force page that displays all the related documents to a custom object. I am displaying this page on a community portal page. This custom object name is CustomDocs__c. This Object is not directly related to the Account or User object therefore I can't use recordId Param or anything else to pull related data. I have to use some Apex to fets the data from the junction object.

Here is what I have so far to accommodate this but its not working, I get nothing in return from this code. Empty list view that's it.

VFP:

```
<apex:page standardController="CustomDocs__c" extensions="DocsLoad">
   
     <apex:pageBlock title="All Docs">
 <apex:pageblockTable value="{!MyDocs}" var="item">
      <apex:relatedList list="item.AttachedContentDocuments" title="test" />
</apex:pageblockTable>
         
 </apex:pageBlock> 
      
</apex:page>
```

APEX:

```
public class DocsLoad{
 public Id RecordId {get;set;}  
    public List<CustomDocs__c> MyDocs {set;get;}   
    
    public DocsLoad(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
   
        GetFiles();
    }
    public void GetFiles()
    {
         Id userId = UserInfo.getUserId();
         String AccountId = [ SELECT AccountId FROM User WHERE Id =: userId].AccountId;
         system.debug(AccountId);
        JunctionObject__c [] Junk = [SELECT Id,Name from JunctionObject__c where Account=:AccountId];
        
        If(Junk .size()>0)
        {
            for(JunctionObject__c JunkObj:Junk)
     {
          MyDocs = [SELECT ID,Name from CustomDocs__c WHERE JunctionObject__c =:JunkObj.Id  ];
          
        
     }
        
        
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Salesforce document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_relatedList.htm), the apex:relatedList can only be used for records related with a lookup or master-detail relationship. I am thinking in your situation you would want to use [apex:repeat](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_repeat.htm). This allows you to go over a list of any SObject and display the fields you would like. Below is an example of the apex:repeat.

```
<apex:page standardController="CustomDocs__c" extensions="DocsLoad">
    <apex:pageBlock title="All Docs">
        <apex:repeat value="{!MyDocs}" var="item">
            <apex:outputField value="{!item.Name}"/>
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Hi @Brook Stang, Thanks for your reply I think you are miss understanding the question here, I am just trying to display the related list of documents, not the Name or just the record.